# In arrayList delete n elements counting from the end

Tags: java, arraylist

So like in the title I have, this method to ask how many elements:

```
//delete elements from deleteFromEnd up to arrayList.size() index
    int deleteFromEnd;
    do
    {
        System.out.format("How many elements you want to delete, counting from end ( less then %d): ", arrayList.size());
        deleteFromEnd = scan.nextInt();
    }while (deleteFromEnd > arrayList.size());
```

Then I'm trying to delete these elements:

```
do
    {
        arrayList.remove(arrayList.size());
        i++;
    }while(i < deleteFromEnd);
```

As you can see, it won't work :D. My problem is that line:

```
arrayList.remove(arrayList.size());
```

Any ideas, what's the best idea to solve this problem?

Comment: `arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);`

Comment: Please do not forget to post the full error message and a full example to test it. Read [mcve], thanks.

Comment: `remove` wants an **index**. Indices are `0`-based. So the first element is at index `0`. The last at `size - 1`, not `size`. Check the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)).

Comment: @Zabuza I didn't get any error, it just didn't worked at all, that's why I didnt post any.

Comment: Then you need to be more precise and explain what exactly is happening and what is expected to happen. And give the full [mcve]. "*It does not work*" is not helpful.

Comment: Right, next time I will be more specific, although almost every time I'm getting help is from people that are advanced in specific topic, so I don't had to explain it exactly. I thought that if I knew what's wrong with specific line, other people will know as well. But for next time I will try to explain problem as good as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java array indexes start from `0`, so the last index for a `List` of size `n` is `n-1`.

However, there is a better way. We obtain a sublist (which is a view on the original `List`, not a copy) for the range we want to remove and then clear that.

```
arrayList.subList(arrayList.size()-deleteFromEnd, arrayList.size()).clear();
```

Comment: this will clear all element from 0 to arrayList.size()-deleteFromEnd

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec Yup, fixed.

Comment: That's really great idea, I read about subList and that's really cool. That's exactly what I wanted to obatain, but didn't knew how, so I used loop :D Thanks for help man.